# Cisco bandwidth guarantee based on remote host address

Tags: cisco, bandwidth

On my cisco I have softphones connecting to some external host. How can I assure to all traffic to/from this external host to have its minimal bandwidth (in case of congestion) of 2Mbit? All other traffic can use free bandwidth, but softphones must have precedence in any way. I am not even bothered for other traffic starvation - just want softphones to have top priority to/from this host. Cisco router is 1800 series. This should also account for download traffic - if comming from this host, it should have priority.

Comment: Learn how to setup QoS on your router - here's the first thing that came up when I googled it - https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2007990

Comment: @hpet, is this external host somewhere on the internet, or is it somewhere else on your coporate WAN?  Without a little more detail, it's difficult to comment.  A diagram showing typical softphone to external host communication would be ideal